# Push spring boot docker image to private registry through jenkins pipeline

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured a private docker registry without any authentication on a local virtual machine. On the same vm server I have jenkins running.

I am trying to create jenkins pipeline for my spring boot maven project to build and push a docker image to a private docker registry.

My spring boot maven plugin configuration in pom.xml looks like below

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name><vm-name>:5000/dev/my-spring-boot-app:v1</name>
                        <publish>true</publish>
                    </image>
                    <docker>
                        <publishRegistry>
                            <url>http://<vm-name>:5000</url>
                        </publishRegistry>
                    </docker>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My Jenkinsfile looks like below

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3.8.1-adoptopenjdk-11'
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2 -v "$pwd":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
            }
        }

        stage('Build Docker image') {
            steps {
                echo "Build Docker Image"
                sh "mvn -DskipTests spring-boot:build-image"
            }
        }
}
```

When this pipeline executes on the jenkins server I get the below error

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.2:build-image (default-cli) @ prototype-be ---
[INFO] Building image '<vm-name>:5000/dev/my-spring-boot-app:v1'
[INFO] 
[INFO] I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->docker://localhost:2376: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [2] No such file or directory
```

Could someone guide me on how my jenkins file should be to build and push the docker image?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. does `vm-name`  comply with: "The hostname must comply with standard DNS rules, but may not contain underscores." ([ref](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/))? 2. `docker://localhost:2376` !?!? (please also configure `docker.builderRegistry` ..to your private one, [ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.docker-registry))

Comment: vm-name is compliant. I added builderRegistry but it further fails with "Invalid Docker builder registry configuration, either token or username/password must be provided". My private docker registry does not have any authentication configured.

Comment: It looks like you can't build your image rather than push it. And building seem to be failing because of no connectivity to docker engine. Check if you have docker engine running and configured properly there - i.e. try "docker ps" command in a separate step and see if it works.

Comment: You are right. Docker is missing in the container jenkins has spawned. What image should I use in the jenkins file? The one that has maven, jdk11 and docker?

Comment: One way would be have docker running on the host and using dind container with mounted docker.sock to it - see here our sample pod for k8s with this config - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-hub-integrations/blob/master/Jenkins/jib-on-kubernetes/Jenkinsfile - you can find relevant examples for Docker as well on the Internet if your setup is docker-based rather than k8s-based. Another way (frequently preferred) would be to use something like kaniko which may be less invasive.